# Why Does Rollup Create a Facade Chunk for my Angular Application Bundle and How to Fix it?

Tags: javascript, angular, bazel, rollup

I have an [Angular 9 application](https://github.com/flolu/centsideas/tree/7c4398d8ca407aefe46fdedab1ac5b11faac75dd/services/client) and I create my bundles with the help of Rollup and Bazel. Thus I have a `rollup_bundle` rule which looks like [this](https://github.com/flolu/centsideas/blob/7c4398d8ca407aefe46fdedab1ac5b11faac75dd/services/client/BUILD.bazel#L105):

```
rollup_bundle(
    name = "bundle",
    config_file = "//packages/angular-bazel:rollup.config.js",
    entry_points = {
        ":main.prod.ts": "index.es2015",
    },
    output_dir = True,
    deps = [
        ":prod_src",
        "@npm//rollup-plugin-commonjs",
        "@npm//rollup-plugin-node-resolve",
    ],
)
```

Here is the [rollup.config.js](https://github.com/flolu/centsideas/blob/7c4398d8ca407aefe46fdedab1ac5b11faac75dd/packages/angular-bazel/rollup.config.js) I am using:

```
const node = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    node({
      mainFields: ['browser', 'es2015', 'module', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
    }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
  onwarn: function (warning) {
    if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') {
      return;
    }
    console.warn(warning.message);
  },
};
```

But during the bundling I get a message that tells me, that Rollup created a facade chunk. Thus I have a seemingly redundant javascript file.

```
INFO: From Bundling JavaScript services/client/bundle [rollup]:

bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/services/client/main.prod.mjs → bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/services/client/bundle...
To preserve the export signature of the entry module "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/services/client/main.prod.mjs", an empty facade chunk was created. This often ha
ppens when creating a bundle for a web app where chunks are placed in script tags and exports are ignored. In this case it is recommended to set "preserveEntrySi
gnatures: false" to avoid this and reduce the number of chunks. Otherwise if this is intentional, set "preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict'" explicitly to silence this warning.
created bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/services/client/bundle in 2.9s
INFO: From Bundling JavaScript services/client/bundle [rollup] [for host]:

bazel-out/host/bin/services/client/main.prod.mjs → bazel-out/host/bin/services/client/bundle...
To preserve the export signature of the entry module "bazel-out/host/bin/services/client/main.prod.mjs", an empty facade chunk was created. This often happens wh
en creating a bundle for a web app where chunks are placed in script tags and exports are ignored. In this case it is recommended to set "preserveEntrySignatures: false" to avoid this and reduce the number of chunks. Otherwise if this is intentional, set "preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict'" explicitly to silence this warning.
created bazel-out/host/bin/services/client/bundle in 3s
```

Here is the directory structure of my application

```
assets
app
shared
environment
features
  login
    store
  user
    store
  ideas
    store
store
```

But I think in order to find the root cause we have to look at the actual source files: https://github.com/flolu/centsideas/tree/7c4398d8ca407aefe46fdedab1ac5b11faac75dd/services/client

Comment: Hi I faced a similar issue when trying the demo starter app for sapper. I found that setting [`preserveEntrySignatures`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/pull/3498) to false made the error go away. Does this help?

Comment: @RichS Mh interesting. The error disappeared! But I still have a javascript bundle with just one line of code: `import"./main.prod-be1afaae.js";`  Not sure if this might be a problem, but hey it seems to work 

Comment: @RichS Just encountered a problem. It seems as if I haven't cleared my cache or something else. But now I get this error in the browser: `Error: inject() must be called from an injection context`. Which is probably an Angular issue

Comment: ok, does this help? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813 . I'm not familiar with the newest Angular. Last Angular I used was v1 (angularjs).